# Context Request Localization in .ashx

Tags: asp.net, datatables, localization, ashx

Im using jquery.datatables with .ashx services in my asp.net project. 
Im sending some Turkish characters (ex;el**ı**te) to service from datatable searchbox. But when im looking this value in service, it seems "elÄ±te"

Whats wrong?

Im using **sAjaxSource** prop in dataTable for this process.

`$('#editable-sample-products').dataTable({
                'bProcessing': true,
                'bServerSide': true,
                'sAjaxSource': '/GHProducts.ashx',
                "aLengthMenu": [
                    [], //[5, 15, 20, -1],
                    [] //[5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
                ],
                // set the initial value
                "iDisplayLength": 15,
                "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": "",//"Sayfa başına _MENU_ kayıt",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sPrevious": "Önceki",
                        "sNext": "Sonraki"
                    }
                },
                "aoColumnDefs": [{
                    'bSortable': false,
                    'aTargets': [0]
                }
                ]
            });`

And its my .ashx service

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
string sSearch = context.Request["sSearch"].ToString();
//and some other codes
}
```

Comment: up... nobody knows?

Comment: You need to examine what is being sent to, and back from, the web server. My initial guess would be that you have character set conversion issues - make sure that you specify the same encoding everywhere - such as Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8